# _d_improd_ directory in uploads breaking site images

Tags: uploads, attachments

I've encountered this weird problem. On a site we're trying to help out on some of their URLs for attachments have become broken.

**URL in post_content**

> wp-content/uploads/2016/04/_d_improd_/13048008_1339117612770400_2521263779841612953_o_f_improf_2048x1365.jpg

**Correct URL**

> wp-content/uploads/2016/04/13048008_1339117612770400_2521263779841612953_o.jpg

If i go into the posts in question and click to edit the image, it knows the correct attachment, then it stores it correctly. It only seems to happen for images in 2016/04 from what they've been able to tel me (The site has 1000s of posts so hard to check them all)

The `_d_improd_` directory does exist, however it only has 4 images inside, none of which are used in any of the posts I've found. They thought this was caused by my speed updates however I reverted to my initial commit from taking their site dump and can;t find any instance of that folder name in my codebase.

Unfortunately searching the net only returns index upon index of people who haven't formatted their servers very well and Google has indexed their directories. When I can find an actual page with the folder referenced it usually someone having a problem with something else who also happened to have `_d_improd_` in their URLs for some reason, but it;s never mentioned.

Does anyone have an idea where this folder could be coming from or be caused by? I'm not looking forward to having to fix this without any idea of the cause, regexing wildly with find replaces on a 2GB database.

Comment: @birgire I think it would be a valid answer to point out that this seems to be caused by extension code. Hiding it in a link in a comment just makes it more confusing.

Comment: ok sure, thanks for the suggestion, I will try to change my comment to an answer ;-) @Rarst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone have an idea where this folder could be coming from or be caused by?

This folder is not created in a plain install of WordPress but it could be created by the [*Image Pro - Image resizing and media management done right*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-pro-wordpress-image-media-management-and-resizing-done-right/) plugin (no longer maintained?) that handles image resizing  among other things.

I tracked down [this part](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/image-pro-wordpress-image-media-management-and-resizing-done-right/trunk/src/thumbs.php) of the plugin:

```
const GENERATED_FILE = '_f_improf_';
const GENERATED_DIR  = '_d_improd_';
```

that seems to match the folder you described.

Comment: This defiantly seems to be the culprit. For some reason while the old dev left dozens of uninstalled plugins on site along with other random unused code, they happened to delete this plugin fully. I managed to confirm with the client that this was indeed in use at one stage to try and speed up the site.

Comment: Glad to hear you sorted this out with the client. @ChrisMorris